# Colours for months

Tags: calendar, mysticism-kabbalah, months

According [inner.org](http://www.inner.org/hebrew_calendar/index), each month of the year has a corresponding colour to it. This does not seem to be in Sefer Yetzirah. What is the source for this and what is the significance with regards to each individual month?

Comment: Are you sure they all actually have corresponding colors, and not that the website thought it looked pretty? On each month’s page I don’t see any description of these colors. Also pretty sure older sefarim wouldn’t differentiate between “lime green” and “pollen green” - they’re just both green.

Comment: In פרדס, שער הגבנים each sefirah is associated with a color. In sefer yetzirah each month is associated with a sefirah so if we combine the two (not that we should) each month is associated with a color but not the colors shown there.